# Using markdown in IMarkerData

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I am trying to implement diagnostics to my language-service. According to the following question I got that I can't use html to customize my 
messages but I can use markdown syntax.

[Can markers support html display just like hoverProvider do?](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/924)

However when I try to use markdown syntax for markers I got the message as it is.

```
 monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(model, this._selector, markers);
 // "# Big Title \\n Please google it   [Google](https://www.google.com) " as a message
```

I got the string as it is.

[image]

Comment: Hello, i encountered the same problem as well(markdown syntax does not work in markers), do you have a solution or any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `code` property of the [IMarkerData](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imarker.html#code) object.

```
{
  ...
  code: {
    target: 'https://www.google.com',
    value: 'Google'
  }
}
```

This will add the link with the text `Google` like this

[image]